# Hypegeometric differential equation

Tags: hypergeometric-function

0

I was wondering if someone, a smart person, can tell me how to transform the following equations (see below) into the well-known Hypergeometric equations. I know that this can be done provided The Mathematica does it, but I need to know the specific rules of transformation: Case 1:

(x^2)*(x+b)f,xx -bxf,x = (a+dx)f

case 2 (x^2)*(x+b)f,xx +(x^2)f,x = (a+dx)f

where b can be positive or negative while a and d are positive.

Thank you for any help that you can provide to this fellow in need. G.W

Comment: This is hard to read. Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: Change of function $f(x)=x^py(x)$ and  determines $p$ to get the hypergeometric ODE with unknown function $y(x)$.